# pubnub invite other people in group chat

Tags: android, pubnub

I am trying to build a group, as well as, one-on-one chat in android using pubnub. The problem I am facing is :

Say I have three users :  A, B, C.

Let's assume all of the three have a pub nub instance running with unique uuid.

A wants to start group chat with B and C. In the backend, I can create a new dynamic channel and then, subscribe A to that channel.

Now, I have to automatically subscribe B and C to that channel, so that A can chat with them.

How do I do it? How do I notify/send update to  B and C that A wants to start a group chat with them?

One option I was thinking of is creating a global channel(G) to which all of users are subscribed. Then, when A wants to have a group chat with B and C,

- create a dynamically generated channel in the backend.
- subscribe A to that channel
- publish a message (containing the uuids of B and C, and    the new
  channel name) to the G channel.
- Now, all others will receive that message from G channel and then,
  B and C will see that the message contains their uuids, so they
  will subscribe to that channel.

But, as it seems, this method is not efficient.

Please suggest how to do it.

Another way to frame the question would be, Can I send events to a pub nub instance provided I only know it's uuid?

EDIT :

I want to cover the following scenarios :

1) A can initiate chat with only B, or only C.

2) A can initiate chat with B and C, or B and D.

3) B should see messages from A in a separate channel, messages from C in a separate channel, and messages from a group chat with A and C in a different channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Pubnub community forum there is no way to communicate directly to the specific subscriber. My suggestion is to create a dedicated channel for each uuid and send to that channel directly. So the app need to subscribe for the channel(its own uuid) on the start up its self.

Comment: Edited my question, does it cover the 3rd scenario?

Comment: From my understanding yes . You could use the dedicated channel (its own uuid ) for some thing like a service messages channel and from that handle each message (one to one or group ) separately .

Comment: Unique, per user channels is exactly how you send a message to a individual user. With the forth coming PubNub BLOCKS, you could have some logic running in PubNub that routes certain message to certain user's. But each user would still have a unique channel they subscribe to. Also, with you will soon be able to provide conditional subscribes to filter the messages you get. Stay tuned on PubNub marketing channels for announcements.